# JQuery forms reloading unexpectedly

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, reload

I have two forms on one page, a login and a register form.
The register form works with the JQuery script flawlessly, but when I submit the login script the page is refreshed?
I have tried both "return false;" and "event.preventDefault();"
This is my latest script with some extra code added.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#login_form").submit(function(){
    l_user=$("#l_user").val();
    l_user=$("#l_pass").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../../functions/login-java.php",
        data: { l_user: l_user, l_pass: l_pass },
        success: function(html){
            if ($.trim(html)=="true")
            {
                $('.l_loader').spin(false);
                $('#login_form').slideUp('slow', function() {
                    $('#login_msg').removeClass('msg_error').addClass('msg_ok');
                    $('#login_msg').html('You are being logged in...');
                    $('#login_msg').slideDown('slow');
                });
            }
            else
            {
                $('.l_loader').spin(false);
                $('#login_msg').removeClass('msg_error').addClass('msg_error');
                $("#login_msg").html(html);
                $("#login_msg").slideDown('slow');
            }
        },
        beforeSend:function()
        {
            $('.l_loader').spin();
        }
    });
    return false;
});
$("#register_form").submit(function(){
    r_name=$("#r_name").val();
    r_user=$("#r_user").val();
    r_email=$("#r_email").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../../functions/register-java.php",
        data: { r_name: r_name, r_user: r_user, r_email: r_email },
        success: function(html){
            if ($.trim(html)=="true")
            {
                $('.r_loader').spin(false);
                $('#register_form').slideUp('slow', function() {
                    $('#register_msg').removeClass('msg_error').addClass('msg_ok');
                    $('#register_msg').html('You have registered! Please check you email to continue.<br />Note: our messages are usually marked as spam.');
                    $('#register_msg').slideDown('slow');
                });
            }
            else
            {
                $('.r_loader').spin(false);
                $('#register_msg').removeClass('msg_error').addClass('msg_error');
                $("#register_msg").html(html);
                $("#register_msg").slideDown('slow');
            }
        },
        beforeSend:function()
        {
            $('.r_loader').spin();
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

});

Comment: You should paste your code here...

Comment: just pointing out, you have two `l_user` variables in login_form submit

Comment: That solved it! thank you @Dhiraj Bodicherla